# Ionic 4: workaround to Ionic Lab black screen error

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

Hi i'm working with ionic 4 and ionic lab and i tried to run the project but I got black screen in the screen when it launch i put the picture of error in console. how I can fix it? I need some help to understand what kind of error is it. thank!

[image]

Comment: Share your code. did you add any Page?

Comment: there are too much files with code and the stack trace didn't show where the error come from . I added stripe paiement in the application and after that it became like this

Comment: check your plugin documents and code you might be missing something or doing something wrong.